# Printing the ASM code to generate the given class

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using eclipse for executing the java program for simple JDBC connection with MySQL with the code as follows:

```
package samm;

import java.sql.*;

public class Sd {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sam", "root", "1234");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from sam1");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3));
            }
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

I am unable to execute and get the desired result but instead, I'm getting an error message as:" Prints the ASM code to generate the given class.
Usage: ASMifier [-debug] "

Comment: **How** are you trying to execute this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line can make a problem :

```
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "  " + rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3));
```

Why because this way is used when you define the name of the attributes in your query so instead of :

```
select * from sam1
```

Your query should look like this :

```
select attribute1, attribute2, attribute3 from sam1
```

---

Second solution instead of defining the index of the attribute you can use your query as it is but you have to change :

```
rs.getInt(1)
```

To this :

```
rs.getInt("name_of_the_attribute");// for example rs.getInt("id")
```